# SQL Server Agent job step - changing the name of the "run as" account

Tags: sql-server, user-accounts, sql-agent-job, sid

If I change the name of the AD user account that is setup as the "Run as" account for the step of an SQL Server Agent job, do I need to update the "Run as" property of the step? Or will it still work using the SID of the account?

Comment: It will work until the service gets restarted I believe. Personally I'd change it anyway, that's stuff is confusing enough as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do not rename accounts, so it is a good question.

Does the AD account still work as a login for SQL Server?

Do you still have access to the database as a user?

What type of job step are you running?

Answers to these questions will help you/me figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, that got me started.